# Using terraform, Is there a way to get the private addresses of tasks running in AWS ECS (FARGATE)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, hazelcast, aws-fargate

I am deploying an Hazelcast cluster into AWS ECS (FARGATE), and everything works fine, now i wanna find a way to have as an output all the Hazelcast members private IP addresses, without accessing the AWS console.

I can provide some the terraform script if necessary
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no way to get the private IP addresses of ECS tasks with Terraform (via the AWS Terraform provider). You would have to add a local provisioner to your Terraform that calls out to the AWS CLI to get the IP addresses.